# how to round off the time value of minutes into hours?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to convert UTC time to pst time and I am able to do it. but I want to round off the minutes' value to '00:00:00'.

what I have written:

```
 SELECT  [TASK_NUMBER]
  , dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,getdate(),dateadd(mi,30,START_TIME),START_TIME),getutcdate()) as START_TIME
  , dateadd(hour,datediff(hour,getdate(),dateadd(mi,30,END_TIME),END_TIME),getutcdate()) as END_TIME
  from table1
```

input:

```
 2017-02-01 12:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-01 23:44:15.160

 2017-02-01 13:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-03 02:44:15.160
```

output:

```
 2017-02-01 12:00:00   ||  2017-02-01 23:00:00

 2017-02-01 13:00:00   ||  2017-02-03 02:00:00
```

Comment: That is not rounding but cutting off, here is a way: **select top 100 cast((cast(cast(START_TIME as date) as char(10)) + ' ' + cast(cast(START_TIME as time) as char(3)) + '00:00') as datetime) from ...**

Comment: I still have to convert UTC time to PST time with in the same Query... hiw do i Do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is **Format()** if 2012+

```
Select Format(START_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
      ,Format(END_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
 From  YourTable
```

Or you can use a simple convert()

```
Select convert(varchar(13),START_TIME,121)+':00:00'
      ,convert(varchar(13),END_TIME,121)  +':00:00'
 From  YourTable
```

Returns

```
2017-02-01 12:00:00    2017-02-01 23:00:00
2017-02-01 13:00:00    2017-02-03 02:00:00
```

Comment: I still have to convert the time from UTC to PST and then i need these changes of rounding the value of hours

Comment: Thank you.. i was looking for it to be more simpler..got the right one

Comment: @Looking_for_answers  Sorry, I had it my head that Start/End was already converted to PST.  I suspect you simply nested the dateadd().  If you need assistance just let me know

Comment: I added the Format(START_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') at the begining of the query and got it.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tblTempTestTableStack

(DataColumn1 DATETIME, DataColumn2 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO tblTempTestTableStack

SELECT SUBSTRING('2017-02-01 12:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-01 23:44:15.160', 1, 23)
            , SUBSTRING('2017-02-01 12:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-01 23:44:15.160', 30, 23)

UNION ALL

SELECT SUBSTRING('2017-02-01 13:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-03 02:44:15.160', 1, 23)
            , SUBSTRING('2017-02-01 13:44:15.160   ||  2017-02-03 02:44:15.160', 30, 23)


SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DATE, DataColumn1) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 
        RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, DataColumn1) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':00:00' + '   ||  '
        + CAST(CONVERT(DATE, DataColumn2) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + 
        RIGHT('00' + CAST(DATEPART(HH, DataColumn2) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':00:00'


FROM tblTempTestTableStack
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not rounding but cutting off, here is a way:

```
select top 100 cast((cast(cast(START_TIME as date) as char(10)) + ' ' + cast(cast(START_TIME as time) as char(3)) + '00:00') as datetime) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, 
    DATEPART(HOUR, START_TIME), 
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST(START_TIME AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)) 
FROM table1
```